# Assign the return object of the superclass to self

Tags: objective-c

I have read many posts about this now but I do not still understand it. I would appriciate an answer rather than a link because I probably already have read it.

```
if (self = [super init]) {

}

return self;
```

When I am calling the [super init] I know I am calling the method on "self"(the objects address) but I am starting the "method-search" in the superclass. When this returns I assign the object type *id* to self...This is where I am getting lost.

Am I assigning "self" as an initialized object up to the point of the superclass to self..?

I understand that I am doing this check to stop the initializing if the superclass implementation of the initializer returns nil however I dont understand what I am assinging to self....I thought self was an address to the current object in memory.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assignment has always seemed a bit hacky to me. Its main point is that the superclass might want to return some other instance than the one that was initially allocated:

```
id foo = [[Foo alloc] init];

@interface Foo : SuperFoo {…}
@implementation Foo

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self)
        …;
    return self;
}

@interface SuperFoo : NSObject {…}
@implementation SuperFoo

- (id) init
{
    [self release];
    return [OtherClass alloc];
}
```

This is crazy indeed, but the fact is that `[super init]` might return an object different from the previous `self`. See [Mike Ash’s blog post](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/the-how-and-why-of-cocoa-initializers.html), that should make things `super` clear.

Comment: Ah, so the only reason you assign the returning object from the superclass implementation of an initializer to self...is because it may return an other object than...self?

Comment: Yes, that’s my understanding of it.

Comment: can you tell me a foundation class which reallocates the instance in the init-method like your SuperFoo?

Comment: Nope, that's not the only reason. The other reason is that the call to `[super init]` might return `nil` if initialization fails, and in this case your `init` method should return `nil` as well.

Comment: @phix: There are some special cases mentioned in the Ash article, like class clusters. I use a much simpler initializer myself because I find the official init idiom appalling and I hope that I will remember this stuff when I subclass something fishy. (It’s probably a disaster waiting to happen :)

Comment: @jlehr: That could be handled by simple `if (![super init])` with a `nil` return value, not needing to assign to self. But I guess this is clear and I’m just nitpicking.

Comment: @zoul: To be honest, I usually just call `[super init]` without even reassigning `self`. While theoretically this might not be robust to future changes in `NSObject`, it's worked pretty well so far (for 20 years or so). :-) When overriding designated initializers of framework classes though, it's probably a good idea to be a little more 'superstitious' and issue the full, Apple-sanctioned mantra.

Comment: Maybe this article is interesting. Wil Shipley writes about a program "[...] that dynamically runs through every class and subclasses them, instantiates the subclasses, and sees if [super init] doesn't return self." http://www.wilshipley.com/blog/2005/07/self-stupid-init.html

Comment: @zoul+@jlehr Here's what I don't understand about the argument over the usefulness of that assignment: The assignment is one line of code _and_ you know that you **must** deal with this stuff with framework-classes anyways. Why not simply make it second nature? Sure, most of the time you'll be subclassing `NSObject` but in that case you don't even _need_ to call `[super init]` there at all, as [it does nothing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/init).

Comment: Adding to ogott's comment: Please **especially** take note of the update in that article, that basically nullifies what Wil Shipley said in that blog-post and its prequel.

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons, why that assignment is important:

1. The designated initializer (di) of the superclass may return `nil` if initialization fails.
   In this case, without the assignment of its return value to `self`, you would end up in a state that is completely unsafe — most likely, your superclass's di will have released the object pointed at by `self` in order to not leak memory.
   If you went on using that instance and you're lucky you should see a crash in the not so distant future. If you're not that lucky, you're going to mess with some other object's internal state and lose or corrupt user-data before your program crashes.
2. There are quite a few classes in Cocoa(Touch) — the class-clusters like `NSString` and `NSArray` probably being the most prominent examples — that may return a different instance from their di.
   The pointer you will receive from `[NSString alloc]` for example will almost definitely not be the same you'll obtain from a subsequent call to `initWithFormat:@"Hello %@!", @"foo"`.

Answer (score 1):

lets break this into smaller chunks:

1- when your calling [super init] your making your super class run its init function first so it can initialize your object that your inheriting, normally that would be NSObject or any superclass that you decided to extend.
the super init functions will return self at the end of that process, just like your doing in your init function

2- when you do the assignment: self = [super init] your actually assigning that return value from your super into your own.

3- the **if** around that assignments actually evaluates the success/failure of the super init call, cause if it failed you would have got a **nil** back and the assignments would have been nil to self. so evaluating nil will return false and you wont run your init code.

4- eventually you also return self (nil if failed / actuall object if it succeeded)

hope that clears it.